Next auth DynamoDB Adapter cannot retrieve sessions from database when using useSession()
After attempting to migrate away from using strategy: "jwt" to strategy: "database" the useSession()  hook no longer retrieves sessions after the user has authenticated. The sessions are being succesfully created in the table within dynamoDb, however it seems they cannot be retrieved. The authentication was working fine before the migration to database:

Even though the sessions are being created by next auth with dynamoDb, useSession now returns sessions as null and undefined:


These are the changes I made as well as the full code below to migrate to database strategy, I don't think I have missed anything:
// @ts-nocheck
import { DynamoDB, DynamoDBClientConfig } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";
import { DynamoDBDocument } from "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb";
import { DynamoDBAdapter } from "@next-auth/dynamodb-adapter";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { checkAuthorization } from "../checkAuthorization";
import returnUser from "../returnUser";


const dynamoDBConfig: DynamoDBClientConfig = {
  region: process.env.NEXT_AUTH_AWS_REGION,
};

const client = DynamoDBDocument.from(new DynamoDB(dynamoDBConfig), {
  marshallOptions: {
    convertEmptyValues: true,
    removeUndefinedValues: true,
    convertClassInstanceToMap: true,
  },
});

try {
  users = JSON.parse(process.env.USERS || "[]");
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error parsing USERS environment variable:", error);
}


const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "Email", type: "text", placeholder: "Enter Email" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        if (!credentials || !credentials.email || !credentials.password) {
          return null;
        }
        const user = users.find((item) => item.email === credentials.email);
        if (user?.password === credentials.password) {
          const modifiedUser = {
            ...user,
          };

          return modifiedUser;
        }
        return null;
      },
    }),
      token: {
        async request(context) {
          try {
            const r = await axios.get(
              `https://${AUTHENTICATOR}.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/${ENVIRONMENT}/authenticator-lambda?code=${context.params.code}`
            );
            return { tokens: r.data };
          } catch (err: any) {
            console.error(err);
            throw new Error(err);
          }
        },
      },
      userinfo: {
        async request(context) {
          return await returnUser(context);
        },
      },
      checks: ["state"],
      async profile(profile) {
        const returnValue = {
          name: profile.name,
          id: profile.id,
          role: profile.role,
          isAuthorized: profile.isAuthorized,
        };
        return returnValue;
      },
    },
  ],
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  pages: {
    signIn: "/signin",
    error: "/autherror",
  },
  adapter: DynamoDBAdapter(client, { tableName: "dev-3-next-auth" }),
  jwt: { secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET },
  session: {
    strategy: "database",
    maxAge: 60 * 15, // 15 min  
    updateAge: 24 * 60 * 60, // 24 hours
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.user = user;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async signIn({ user, account }) {
      return checkAuthorization(user, account);
    },
    async session({ session, user }) {
      session.user.id = user.id;
      return session;
    },
  },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

